# What should I look for in a spinning 22lr target?

Tags: rifles, target-shooting

I am looking to get a spinning 22lr target, the fun thing about these is that if you hit them the target spins and then resets so it's very clear that you either hit or missed.

There are all different types and kinds of these, what features should I look for?

Answer (score 3):

Most of these I have experience with the supporting arms are the weak point - hit them and they bend, making it hard to take the target apart for storage, keeping the target from spinning/flipping, etc.

A spring loaded "popper" style target may work better/longer without issues.  Alternatively, a hanging target and have it hung from (small) chains.

I've seen various retailers with rimfire-appropriate size targets in both popper configuration (IPSC type silhouette, dinosaur shape, squirrel, etc) and hanging circular disks (4" to 8" diameter) for not much in the past few months.

As always, keep the target a safe distance away, use eye protection, be aware of where any ricochets or misses may land, etc.

Safe shooting!

Comment: Question:  In regards to metal targets, shouldn't the face of the target be angled downward to prevent bound back?  If the face is pointing downward, the bullet should not be able to come straight back to the shooter, Correct?.

Comment: @B540Glenn - if the target is at a fixed angle, yes.  If it can spin, then it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the durability issue @ivanivan mentioned, if you hit the "stem" that is common to nearly all spinners, you might take that as a hit when in fact it was a miss.

You should also look at Champion Target's [Duraseal](http://www.championtarget.com/targets/interactive/duraseal.aspx) series, which are a bit more environmentally friendly as there is no lead splatter/dust. Of course, they will eventually need replacing so that is the main con. They have several styles. You should try some of the ground-based or hanging targets, too. [Shooting at a moving target takes more skill anyway](https://youtu.be/EpU3l_3DiTA) than a stationary spinner and works on your target transitions and acquisition regardless of whether you are using a .22 rifle or a handgun. **You do need to be very aware of your backstop though as well as potentially skipping bullets off the ground over it so don't chase the target out of the zone you know will be safe.**